# Why was the depiction of the town changed at the end?

Tags: analysis, hansel-and-gretel

During the course of [*Hansel & Gretel: Witch Hunters*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1428538/) the town of Augsburg is repeatedly depicted in a rather rural style, with half-timbered clay houses and dirt streets, as seen on this screenshot from *Mina*'s trial at the beginning:
[image]

Yet at the end (and only there), when *Hansel* and *Gretel* get their pay for returning the children, it shows a much higher developed part of the town, with large stone buildings and cobblestone streets, as seen here:
[image]

Is there any information **if this change of depicting the town at the end was done on purpose?** And if yes, **what is the meaning of this** (was it maybe just to emphasize the effect of the happy ending)?

(Of course it could also be that there wasn't much more to it and it was just a natural consequence of them being at a different part of town, but the difference to the previous depictions of the town struck me as pretty significant.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking at two areas of the same town - the village parts where regular people live and work, and the city center/ market square - where the wealthier business people, government and church would be, and where the heroes would be honored for their great deeds.

Some interesting links about the sets:

http://carlyreddin.com/Hansel-Gretel-Witch-Hunters Click through to the next two pages to see hand drawings of the village sets

http://whatculture.com/film/set-report-hansel-gretel-witch-hunters.php Explains (with photos) how they transformed the castle square in Brunswick into a medieval market for the film

http://www.flickr.com/photos/bondbulletin/sets/72157626395815566/ More photos of the market place where the witch burning was filmed

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoaqIapj0dI Video of the village settings from the Babelsburg film studio